# Form submits to itself: how to I create a back link that works on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these 2 codes:

```
<a id="back" href="##">Click here to go back</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#back").on("click tap", function(event) {
        window.history.back();

        return false;
    });
});
```

works great on desktop devices and no go on mobile. if I tap/click on the link, the page just refreshes itself. Any ideas on how to make it work? thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

Replace this line

```
$("#back").on("click tap", function(event) {
```

with:

```
$("#back").on("click tap touchend", function(event) {
```

### Result:

```
<a id="back" href="##">Click here to go back</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#back").on("click tap touchend", function(event) {
        window.history.back();

        return false;
    });
});
```